# Not receiving broadcast from k9 email

Tags: android, email, broadcastreceiver

I am listening for the email received broadcast from k9 and I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have registered a receiver for the following:

```
com.fsck.k9.intent.action.EMAIL_RECEIVED
```

I'm wondering if I need to add a permission - I can't seem to receive this broadcast.

I know my receiver is working as I can receive broadcasts for SMS and the phone. Has anyone else used this that can maybe shed some light on the subject?

Here's my filter:

```
IntentFilter fltr = new IntentFilter();
fltr.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
fltr.addAction("com.fsck.k9.intent.action.EMAIL_RECEIVED");
fltr.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
registerReceiver(mRcv, fltr);
```

In my BroadcastReceiver:

```
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String EMAIL_RECEIVED = "com.fsck.k9.intent.action.EMAIL_RECEIVED";
private static final String CALL_RECEIVED = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";


public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "Inside Broadcast Reciever");
            Log.d(TAG, "Action: " + intent.getAction());
            if(intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                StartAct("SMS Received", context);
            }else if(intent.getAction().equals(EMAIL_RECEIVED)){
                StartAct("Email received", context);
            }else if(intent.getAction().equals(CALL_RECEIVED)){
                if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                    StartAct("Incoming Phone Call", context);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you need permission? I've not done K9 receivers, but I know for the SMS and phone you need permission, does the K9 say anything about needing to declare a permission?

Comment: I'm not sure about the permissions - that is what I would like to find out. I'm not sure where to look to see if it is needed. The wiki page about the broadcast intent doesn't state anything about permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I have it working - finally....

You have to add a data scheme to the intent filter. This will allow you to receive the broadcast. BUT it will break the other actions that I had in the filter, so I had to break them into separate receivers - one for SMS and phone and another for the k9 email broadcast.

Here's the one for k9 email:

```
IntentFilter fltr = new IntentFilter();
fltr.addAction("com.fsck.k9.intent.action.EMAIL_RECEIVED");
fltr.addDataScheme("email"); //This is needed to even receive the broadcast
registerReceiver(mRcv, fltr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the actual K9 [source code](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9). The [AndroidManifest](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) shows several Permissions that they have. Try compiling your program with it hooked up to eclipse and check LogCat, it'll usually show in it's error section if there is a missing permission. I only see 4 declared permissions that they have created, so READ_MESSAGE would be my guess, but check the logcat and see what it says.

Unfortunately it looks like their documentation is lacking quite a bit, which is a damn shame.